# Why does Reagent render JSON in three ways?

Tags: json, clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to render JSON data from an API call in Clojurescript/Reagent.  When I use `js/alert` I see the json I expect: `["Sue" "Bob"]`

```
(defn- call-api [endpoint]
  (go
    (let [response (<! (http/get endpoint))]
      (:names (:body response)))))

;; -------------------------
;; Views

(defn home-page []
  [:div (call-api "/api/names")])
```

This is how I'm referencing the libraries (in case there's an problem there).

```
(ns myapp.core
    (:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
              [reagent.session :as session]
              [cljs-http.client :as http]
              [cljs.core.async :refer [<! >!]]
              [secretary.core :as secretary :include-macros true]
              [accountant.core :as accountant])
    (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]]))
```

But when I log it to the console, I get a long hash that looks nothing like the API response.  The browser renders "00000000000120".

- Why do these results differ?  (browser, alert window, console message)
- How can I get what I'm seeing in the alert window to render on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `call-api` it is going to return a go block. Instead of trying to consume that go block directly in your Reagent function, you could instead update the return value in a ratom.

```
(def app-state (atom)) ;; ratom

(defn- call-api [endpoint]
  (go
    (let [response (<! (http/get endpoint))]
      (reset! app-state (:names (:body response))))))

(defn home-page []
  [:div @app-state])

(defn main []
  (call-api))
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  Could you expand on "You will need to <! on the result of the go block somewhere"?  Do you mean `>!`?  A code snippet of what should be in `defn home-page` would be most helpful. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an (untested) code snippet which should show the general idea.

Comment: Great success!  Not sure why his has to go through an atom, but this will move me forward.  Thank you!

Comment: Join the Clojurians Slack, the #reagent channel can explain the reasoning further :)